# Understanding the word "is" in mathematical definitions.

Tags: geometry, logic, proof-writing

Working on the book: Lang, Serge & Murrow, Gene. "Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 133)

> Theorem **4-2**. In general, let $a, b$ be two numbers, and $r$ a number $> 0$. Then, the equation of the circle of radius $r$, centered at $(a, b)$, is the equation:
> $$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$$

> This means that the circle is the set of all points satisfying this equation.

My question has two parts.

**Part one**:

- What's the meaning and logical symbolization of the word "is", in general, and in this particular case ? Is an "if and only if" connective used for its symbolisation ?

**Part two**:

Example:

"Geometry - Second Edition" (p. 140)

> **Theorem 5-2**. Let $P, Q, A$ be the three vertices of a triangle. Then:

> (a) The perpendicular bisectors of the three sides meet in one point.

> (b) There exists a unique circle passing through the three points $P, Q, A$, and the center of that circle is the common point of the perpendicular bisectors of the sides.

- How does the word "is" actually being used when doing a proof of uniqueness ?

On point (b), it would be necessary to suppose there exists another circle, and conclude that in fact, there is only one.

- Assuming another circle passes through those points; it suffices to show they have the same center ? How is the definition stated above "instantiated" for the assumption that another circle exists ? What's the role of the word "is" in this uniqueness proof ?

Comment: "Is" is the third-person singular of "to be".

Comment: Is English your first language?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The meaning of definition written in the form ... is...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3767906/the-meaning-of-definition-written-in-the-form-is)

Comment: Thank you so much, @lemontree. I always appreciate your insight. That's exactly what I was looking for. So, the symbol being used would be ":=". Only remains one part of my question; how to use it in proofs. Would be considered an abbreviation in a Natural Deduction proof, perhaps ? There is no Elimination Rule for it, of course. Should I start another question ?

Comment: If you want to know how definitions can be treated formally, you might be interested in what Kennet Kunen says about extensions by definitions in his textbook The Foundations of Mathematics. Some other books on mathematical logic might discuss this as well, but that's where I've seen it.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Martti Karvonen. I am glancing at it and seems very useful for me. Are you referring to section 1.6 "Extensionality, Comprehension, Pairing, Union" ? If not, could you point me to the specific section of the book ?

Comment: No, I meant the section literally titled "extensions by definitions", which seems to be  section II.15.

Comment: Found it, thank you @Martti Karvonen.

Comment: @F. Zer Formalized into predicate logic, one would write definitions as a universally quantified biimplication, e.g. $\forall x (prime(x) \leftrightarrow \forall y \forall z (y \cdot z = x \to (y = 1 \lor z = 1)))$, so the corresponding rule in a proof to unpack the definition would be biconditional elimination.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, @lemontree. For such a long time, I wanted to understand what you just explained. Your example using the definition of a prime number, also helped. Thank you.